# Segementation fault uwsgi

Tags: uwsgi

Not sure if it's a repetition question
I'm able to run http but when using https I'm getting the errors.
this is the config I'm using

```
shared-socket = :443 
protocol = https
https = =0,cert.crt,cert.key
master = true 
processes = 4 
threads = 2
wsgi-file = /home/ubuntu/project/foo.py 
callable  = application
```

this is the backtrace

```
*** backtrace of 18280 ***
uwsgi(uwsgi_backtrace+0x33) [0x5580ef3ada63]
uwsgi(uwsgi_segfault+0x27) [0x5580ef3ade97]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x42520) [0x7f084b642520]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3(SSL_get_rbio+0x4) [0x7f084c5c0144]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3(SSL_set_bio+0x1c) [0x7f084c5c018c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3(SSL_set_fd+0x44) [0x7f084c5c0374]
uwsgi(uwsgi_proto_ssl_accept+0x5e) [0x5580ef3b3dee]
uwsgi(wsgi_req_accept+0x1e5) [0x5580ef35bb25]
uwsgi(simple_loop_run+0xae) [0x5580ef3a942e]
uwsgi(simple_loop+0x7b) [0x5580ef3a951b]
uwsgi(uwsgi_ignition+0x299) [0x5580ef3ae1e9]
uwsgi(uwsgi_worker_run+0x272) [0x5580ef3b2922]
uwsgi(uwsgi_run+0x465) [0x5580ef3b2ea5]
uwsgi(+0x3ee64) [0x5580ef35ae64]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x29d90) [0x7f084b629d90]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x80) [0x7f084b629e40]
uwsgi(_start+0x25) [0x5580ef35ae95]
*** end of backtrace ***
```